# get android contact display options programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-contacts

I want to display contacts in my application with following criteria:

contacts those match display options setting in android contacts.

So if in android contact display option "sim contacts" is not marked then android contact will not display those sim card contacts. So now i want to get those display options and according to that i want to display contact in my application as well.

Comment: [see this tuts](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-read-contact-and-display-in.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i found the solution by going with this code:

```
final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
String[] projection = { ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.Contacts._ID };
String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = ?";
String[] selectionArgs = { "1" };
final Cursor contacts = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection,
                        selection, selectionArgs, 
                        "UPPER(" + ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + ") ASC");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this demo

http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/read-contacts-from-device/